# ZedGraph: just the dots

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, zedgraph

I am new to [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/). So far I could draw curves and bars. How can I display just the dots without connecting them?

I am using C# and [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms).

Answer (score 12):

The [Scatter Plot Demo](https://web.archive.org/web/20110215041641/http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Scatter_Plot_Demo) from ZedGraph's site shows how to do it. There is an `IsVisible` property on the Line which you set to `false` to only show the points.

```
LineItem myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Title", list, Color.Black, SymbolType.Diamond);
myCurve.Line.IsVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is [on The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx). Have a look at the part where he talks about "The Fill class". There is a dot-only example.